# How to find out which systemd services/units are part of a target unit?

Tags: linux, systemd

So if I run `systemctl list-units --type=target` I can see all of the target units on my machine.

But if I wanted to find a list of services and other units that are under each of these "umbrella" target units, how could I do that?

In other words, if I see with `journalctl` that I have a `UNIT` xyz, how would I know which target that unit belongs to?

I see in the journal messages that say "Reached target `<target_name>`", but I'm curious what log messages and units lead up to that target being reached.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I think you are looking for `list-dependencies`.

From the man page:

```
       list-dependencies [UNIT]
           Shows units required and wanted by the specified unit. This
           recursively lists units following the Requires=, Requisite=,
           ConsistsOf=, Wants=, BindsTo= dependencies. If no unit is
           specified, default.target is implied.

           By default, only target units are recursively expanded. When --all
           is passed, all other units are recursively expanded as well.

           Options --reverse, --after, --before may be used to change what
           types of dependencies are shown.
```

For example:

```
# systemctl list-dependencies zfs.target
zfs.target
● ├─zfs-mount.service
● ├─zfs-share.service
● ├─zfs-zed.service
● └─zfs-import.target
●   └─zfs-import-cache.service
```